# ошибка создания bean-компонента с именем «entityManagerFactory», определенным в ресурсе пути к классу

Tags: java, telegram-bot, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Целый день бьюсь с подключением телеграмм бота к БД. Одна и та же ошибка постоянно, а опыта прочитать и понять у меня нет. я прошерстил весь инет и перебрал каждую строчку в файле: **application.properties**
Но решить ошибку не смог.
**Вот она:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
```

**Файл application.properties**

```
bot.name=XXXXXXXXXXX
bot.token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

#data properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_bot
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.consol
```

**TelegramBot:**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BotConfig botConfig;
    private static final String HELP_TEXT = "This bot is created to demonstrate Spring capabilities.\n\n" +
            "You can execute commands from the main menu on the left or by typing a command:\n\n" +
            "Type /start to see a welcome message\n\n" +
            "Type /mydata to see data stored about yourself\n\n" +
            "Type /help to see this message again";

    @Autowired
    public TelegramBot(BotConfig botConfig) {
        this.botConfig = botConfig;
        List<BotCommand> listOfCommand = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/start", "Вывести приветственное сообщение"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/mydata", "Показать информацию"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/deletedata", "Удалить Данные"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/help","Вывести все команды"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/setting","Настройки"));
        try {
            this.execute(new SetMyCommands(listOfCommand,new BotCommandScopeDefault(),null));
        } catch (TelegramApiException exe) {
            log.error("Error occurred:" + exe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return botConfig.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return botConfig.getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()){
            String message = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();

            switch (message){
                case "/start":

                    registerUser(update.getMessage());
                    startCommandReceived(chatId,update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "/help":
                    sendMessage(chatId,HELP_TEXT);
                    break;
                default:
                    sendMessage(chatId,"Мне нечего сказать");
            }
        }

    }

    private void registerUser(Message message) {
        if (userRepository.findById(message.getChatId()).isEmpty()){
            var chatId = message.getChatId();
            var chat = message.getChat();

            User user = new User();

            user.setChatId(chatId);
            user.setFirstName(chat.getFirstName());
            user.setLastName(chat.getLastName());
            user.setUserName(chat.getUserName());
            user.setRegisteredAt(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            userRepository.save(user);
            log.info("User saved: " + user);
        }
    }

    protected void startCommandReceived(long chatId, String name){
        String answer = "Привет, " + name + " и Добро пожаловать!";
        log.info("replied to the user: " + name);
        sendMessage(chatId,answer);
    }
    protected void sendMessage(long chatId, String textToSend){
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
        sendMessage.setText(textToSend);

        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException exe) {
            log.error("Error occurred:" + exe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Таблица Users**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usersDataTable")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Long chatId;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private Timestamp registeredAt;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getChatId() {
        return chatId;
    }

    public void setChatId(Long chatId) {
        this.chatId = chatId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Timestamp getRegisteredAt() {
        return registeredAt;
    }

    public void setRegisteredAt(Timestamp registeredAt) {
        this.registeredAt = registeredAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "chatId=" + chatId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", registeredAt=" + registeredAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Так же есть интерфейс репозитория этой таблицы

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long>
```

Так же я перерыл все свои зависимости думая что проблема в них

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ai.joy</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoBot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <telegram.version>5.6.0</telegram.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>${telegram.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
            <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

весь лог ошибки:

```
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$1.execute(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$1.execute(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at ai.joy.demoBot.DemoBotApplication.main(DemoBotApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Добавьте весь лог ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Ошибка `Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]` говорит, что не существует такого диалекта, и его действительно нет на [гитхабе `Hibernate`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/).  К тому же используется версия JDBC драйвера 42.2.18, которая вышла за два года (в октябре 2020) до того, как был выпущен PostgreSQL 15.  Попробуйте использовать "обычный" диалект `PostgreSQLDialect`, рекомендуемый для версии PostgreSQL 11+ и обновите драйвер до 42.5.1

Comment: @NowhereMan Я обновил драйвер и вписал обычный диалект. Даже на всякий случай обновил драйвер до версии 42.7.2.
теперь ошибка выглядит так:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement`

Comment: Ну эту песню надо начинать сначала -- редактировать текст, указывать сообщения об ошибке с логами.  Скорее всего, зависимость `javax.xml` "пропала", так как она была исключена в JDK 11 и выше, её надо подключать вручную.