# ошибка создания bean-компонента с именем entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, telebot, hibernate

Создаю простого телеграмм бота. Обыскал все ссылки даже сменил разные версии драйверов postgres и это помогло, но ошибка поменяла свой характер.
**Вот она:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at ai.joy.demoBot.DemoBotApplication.main(DemoBotApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:137) ~[jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:124) ~[jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule.setupModule(JaxbAnnotationModule.java:98) ~[jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:879) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModules(ObjectMapper.java:1081) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules(ObjectMapper.java:1165) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper.<init>(JacksonJsonFormatMapper.java:26) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonIntegration.<clinit>(JacksonIntegration.java:18) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.lambda$determineJsonFormatMapper$6(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:803) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.determineJsonFormatMapper(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.createSessionFactoryBuilder(DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.java:26) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Прошёл месяц. каждый вечер пытаюсь биться с этой ошибкой хотя бы по часу в день и ничего.
**Вот файлы проекта
Файл application.properties:**

```
bot.name=*************
bot.token=***************************

#data properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_bot
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
```

**TelegramBot:**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BotConfig botConfig;
    private static final String HELP_TEXT = "This bot is created to demonstrate Spring capabilities.\n\n" +
            "You can execute commands from the main menu on the left or by typing a command:\n\n" +
            "Type /start to see a welcome message\n\n" +
            "Type /mydata to see data stored about yourself\n\n" +
            "Type /help to see this message again";

    @Autowired
    public TelegramBot(BotConfig botConfig) {
        this.botConfig = botConfig;
        List<BotCommand> listOfCommand = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/start", "Вывести приветственное сообщение"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/mydata", "Показать информацию"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/deletedata", "Удалить Данные"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/help","Вывести все команды"));
        listOfCommand.add(new BotCommand("/setting","Настройки"));
        try {
            this.execute(new SetMyCommands(listOfCommand,new BotCommandScopeDefault(),null));
        } catch (TelegramApiException exe) {
            log.error("Error occurred:" + exe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return botConfig.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return botConfig.getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()){
            String message = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();

            switch (message){
                case "/start":

                    registerUser(update.getMessage());
                    startCommandReceived(chatId,update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "/help":
                    sendMessage(chatId,HELP_TEXT);
                    break;
                default:
                    sendMessage(chatId,"Мне нечего сказать");
            }
        }

    }

    private void registerUser(Message message) {
        if (userRepository.findById(message.getChatId()).isEmpty()){
            var chatId = message.getChatId();
            var chat = message.getChat();

            User user = new User();

            user.setChatId(chatId);
            user.setFirstName(chat.getFirstName());
            user.setLastName(chat.getLastName());
            user.setUserName(chat.getUserName());
            user.setRegisteredAt(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            userRepository.save(user);
            log.info("User saved: " + user);
        }
    }

    protected void startCommandReceived(long chatId, String name){
        String answer = "Привет, " + name + " и Добро пожаловать!";
        log.info("replied to the user: " + name);
        sendMessage(chatId,answer);
    }
    protected void sendMessage(long chatId, String textToSend){
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
        sendMessage.setText(textToSend);

        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException exe) {
            log.error("Error occurred:" + exe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Таблица Users:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usersDataTable")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long chatId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private Timestamp registeredAt;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getChatId() {
        return chatId;
    }

    public void setChatId(Long chatId) {
        this.chatId = chatId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Timestamp getRegisteredAt() {
        return registeredAt;
    }

    public void setRegisteredAt(Timestamp registeredAt) {
        this.registeredAt = registeredAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "chatId=" + chatId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", registeredAt=" + registeredAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Так же есть интерфейс репозитория этой таблицы

`public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long>`

Так же я перерыл все свои зависимости думая что проблема в них

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ai.joy</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoBot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <telegram.version>5.6.0</telegram.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>${telegram.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
            <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: я этого же бота писал сидел и думал я туплю что-то, но оказывается нет, кучу зависимостей пробовал разных в помник прописать, но не помогает, как я понимаю там конфликт версий в библиотеках идёт, проще короче забить и искать другой туториал)))

Comment: @EricbubiCartman Так программистом не стать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии к [прошлому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1567218/), было указано, что "новая" проблема `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement` связана с тем, что соответствующий API был удалён ещё в Java 11 ([JEP 320](https://openjdk.org/jeps/320)), а в данном проекте используется как минимум Java 17.

***Исправленный вариант***
Проблема с зависимостью библиотеки Jackson (даже новых её версий) от достаточно старого API `javax.xml.bind` известна и её решение описано в [гитхабе](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/discussions/4055#discussioncomment-6526838) в июле прошлого года:

- [#4055: `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement` with JDK 17 and Jackson 2.13.4](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/discussions/4055)

Поэтому в `pom.xml` следует добавить зависимость на [`jaxb-api` версии 2.3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1), как наиболее подходящее решение:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

При использовании же более новых версий этого API `jakarta.xml.bind-api` потребуется также выполнить миграцию соответствующих библиотек.

Comment: Добавил зависимость и... та же ошибка...

Comment: @ЖеняРасс, выложите свой проект на гитхаб и дайте ссылку на него.

Comment: [ссылка](https://github.com/Zifir0k/demoBot)
@Nowhere Man

Comment: @ЖеняРасс, нашёл правильную версию артефакта `javax.xml.bind::jaxb-api` -- это версия 2.3.1, с ней проект должен успешно собраться и запуститься.

Comment: Ты бог?) Спасибо большое)